# Hbase rowkey design for time range query

Tags: hbase

I need to get page view of product from start date to end date. So i design Hbase rowkey like this.

```
ProductId(md5)_productId_dateKey(yyyymmdd)  d:pageview.
```

Example: productId is 1180560. The rowkey from 1st August to 30th August will be:

```
0f0e02e9e24c29ad2c2b28e37e4f250b_1180560_20150801

.....

0f0e02e9e24c29ad2c2b28e37e4f250b_1180560_20150830
```

So i will easily get product pageview for time range  by  scanning rowkey with start row, stop row

My questions are:

Does this design avoid hotspotting ?

The length of rowkey seem too long. Will it effect the performance ?.

Is there a way to shorten the rowkey and still ensure avoid hotspotting, collision.

Is there better design for this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Hotspotting : It is always advisable not to use sequential row keys, even though you get better scan results. More info [here](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/rowkey.design.html).

Length of row key - For each cell, rowkey details, column family, and qualifier details are stored. So it is always advisable to keep them as shot as possible, mainly because the same information is repeated on large scale.

So whats next - salt usage and its prefixing will help to distribute the rows among region servers. [This](http://blog.sematext.com/2012/04/09/hbasewd-avoid-regionserver-hotspotting-despite-writing-records-with-sequential-keys/) can help you

Comment: Its seem that my design is right, but the rowkey length is 49 character. Is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to md5 your productId. Just compute remainder according to no of region server you would like. i.e. key split.

So, if you want 0 to 4 (total 5 split) then you need to build you key as

```
Bytes(StringValue(productID%5)) + Bytes(productId) + Bytes(timestamp)
```

For example for product id 1180560

```
1180560%5=0
Bytes.toBytes(1180560)
Bytes.toBytes(timestamp)
```

Now you can query your data by using prefix scan.

Example code in Java to get 5 days of data for same product:

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -2); // deduct 2 days
byte[] STARTROW = Bytes.add(Bytes.toBytes( productID%5),Bytes.toBytes(productID),Bytes.toBytes(cal.getTime().getTime()));
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +3); //add 3 days
byte[] ENDTROW = Bytes.add(Bytes.toBytes( productID%5),Bytes.toBytes(productID),Bytes.toBytes(cal.getTime().getTime()));
byte[] prefix = Bytes.add(Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(remainder)), 
Scan scan = new Scan(STARTROW,ENDTROW);
scan.setFilter(prefixFilter);
```